Confusion with Type Mismatch in ModelMapper Code Using Java 17
I am currently using Java 17 along with ModelMapper to convert objects from one type to another.
I came across a confusing scenario where I assign the result of a method that returns a List<Test> to a new ArrayList<Boolean>.
Later, I attempt to add a boolean value to this list, and it surprisingly compiles and gives an output, which I'm struggling to understand.
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

public final class ModelMapperAdapter {

    private static ModelMapper MODEL_MAPPER;

    public static class Test{
        Integer var;
        //getter
        //setter
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MODEL_MAPPER = new ModelMapper();
        Test test = new Test();
        List<Test> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Boolean> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(test);
        ids.addAll(MODEL_MAPPER.map(list, new TypeToken<List<Test>>(){}.getType()));
        System.out.println(ids);//[ModelMapperAdapter.Test(var=null)]
        ids.add(true);
        System.out.println(ids);//[ModelMapperAdapter.Test(var=null), true]     
    }
}



The problem is that the ModelMapper.map(Object source, Type destinationType) method makes promises that it cannot fulfill.
If you look at the complete method signature:
public <D> D map​(Object source, Type destinationType)

it pretends that for any source object and type descriptor destinationType it will return an instance of D.
The problem is that D and the destinationType don't need to be related.
Due to the way the method signature is written:

the Java Compiler cannot verify that those two types are related (Type destinationType is not generic). If the Java Compiler could verify it the code would not compile.
the ModelMapper.map() method has no way of knowing what D is and therefore cannot check that you are using the method correctly. If it could verify what D is it could throw an exception at runtime.

That means that (when using ModelMapper) it is your responsability to make sure that D refers the same type as destinationType.

Note that this problem (together with performance problems) is the reason I stopped using ModelMapper years ago and replaced it with MapStruct

It would work if destinationType’s declared type was TypeToken<D>…

If Java ArrayLists support heterogeneous elements but we cannot efficiently iterate over and use these values, what is the purpose of generics? For instance, in this case, a Boolean ArrayList includes a toString method from the Test class.
